# After upgrade 2.5 to joomla 3.5 custom plugin doesn't work

Tags: joomla, upgrade

My debug stack says :
JHtml image not found.

> Call stack
>
> **Function Location**
>
> 1 JApplicationCms->execute()  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:49
>   2 JApplicationSite->doExecute()   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\cms\application\cms.php:257
>   3 JApplicationSite->dispatch()    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\cms\application\site.php:230
>   4 JComponentHelper::renderComponent() C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\cms\application\site.php:191
>   5 JComponentHelper::executeComponent()    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\cms\component\helper.php:380
>   6 require_once()  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\cms\component\helper.php:405
>   7 JControllerLegacy->execute()    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\components\com_incidentmap\incidentmap.php:131
>   8 IncidentController->display()   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\legacy\controller\legacy.php:728
>   9 JControllerLegacy->display()    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\components\com_incidentmap\controller.php:31
>   10    IncidentViewFlorida->display()  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\legacy\controller\legacy.php:690
>   11    JViewLegacy->display()  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\components\com_incidentmap\views\florida\view.html.php:31
>   12    JViewLegacy->loadTemplate() C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\legacy\view\legacy.php:209
>   13    include()   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libraries\legacy\view\legacy.php:670
>   14    JHtml::_()  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\components\com_incidentmap\views\florida\tmpl\default.php:8

Please help me fix this

Comment: Where is your plugin code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the problematic code with:

```
JHtml::image($file, $alt, $attribs = null, $relative = false, $returnPath = 0)
```

Of course, you will need to replace the parameters above with your values.

I think you were using `JHtml::_('image.site',...` which no longer exists in Joomla 3.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. You are right I was using (image.site). I was getting lots of issues due to migration that I have fix using below link :